# Как поменять версию SDK у андроид файла?

Tags: c#, android, apk, deserialize

имеется игра на Unity. Забилженный файл, иходников нет. На старой версии Android игра запускается и работает отлично. Начиная с Android 6 и тд, игра вылетает после заставки. Есть ли возможность сменить версию SDK, как например в Android Studio? СРОЧНО

Пробовал десериализововать apk, но может конечно я е там искал, я е нашел файла, где будет смена SDK версии.

Comment: Изменение версии SDK может только добавить проблем, но не решить их. Она указывает системе для какой версии приложение создано и система может включать опции обратной совместимости. Если вы повысите версию, то никаких поблажек приложению не будет.